# Convert existing object model to Core Data managed object model

Tags: ios, core-data, model, nsmanagedobject

I am developing an iOS app and have several object models. Now I want to convert them to core data managed objects, so creating the entities and attributes from the object instead of the standard opposite way of generating the objects from the model. What is the best way to accomplish this?

I tried extending from `NSManagedObject` instead of `NSObject`, then manually creating the entities and attributes and setting up the Class name for the entity but that didn't work :-(

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this question of mine. I had the same problem, and maybe can cover part of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352586/impact-of-core-data-on-existing-project-iphone , also I am now in the opinion that CoreData needs a full revision of the model, in particular to make proper use of that in a UI

Comment: @Leonardo thanks, interesting read. But in one of your posts you said you connected your class to the entity, how do you do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently did this for a big project with a very large and complex data model. Here is a workflow that I found to be very feasible.

First, I create a new data model in Xcode and populate it by hand. This is a very good exercise as it forces you to review your model and perhaps take advantage of simplification opportunities.

Then, generate your class files with Xcode from the model. If you have any special code that should be included in the objects, add them as categories in separate files (e.g. Event.h & Event.m generated by Xcode, Event+Additions.h & Event+Additions.m with your code).

Comment: +1 for adding addition code as a category. Incase you need to regenerate the class files from an updated model, you will not lose the additional code.

Comment: Thanks @Mundi and agreed with ColdLogic